# Display data based on date in url

Tags: php, testing

I'm trying to echo certain details of a specific user defined in the url (like this: **search_result.php?lastname=Doe&date_of_birth=1964-04-12**)

```
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['lastname']); 
$dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['date_of_birth']); 
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qfever WHERE lastname = '$lname' AND date_of_birth = '$dob'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$date_of_birth = $row['date_of_birth'];
$employee_number = $row['employee_number'];
}
echo $firstname;
echo $lastname;
echo $date_of_birth;
echo $employee_number;
```

​
I can echo what it picks up from the url but it does not echo the user's details from the database.
Could the problem be the format of the dates?
My **date_of_birth** column in the database is currently set to **TEXT** but the HTML input type is set to **DATE**.

Comment: But your url has no employee_number

Comment: I updated my question, it should be clearer now

Comment: can you confirm if the date_of_birth field in the table is in which type?

Comment: date_of_birth field is set to text

Comment: Try turning on error reporting. You'd find the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: that might be an issue with the current host that I'm using

Comment: First, you're mixing mysqli and mysql. Second, you have the wrong syntax for `_real_escape_string` in either variant. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.

Comment: Thanks! Everything's working fine now

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes in your code:

- First you do not escape the variable fed in the mysql query. You should at least use mysql_real_escape_string.
- You get the wrong field in the `$_GET` global and does the wrong request too.
- You forgot to put the variable between quotes, which makes the request fail I believe.
- You map all your `$res[X]` to `$X`. What's the point ?
- You print `$firstname` outside the loop and thus get only the last one.

Comment: You fixed points 2 and 5 but not the rest. Especially 3 (the quotes) which I think lead to a syntax error in SQL.

Comment: i have to fill each field of a form with the employee's details, thats why i map to $X

Answer (score 1):

Change your query

```
  SELECT * FROM qfever WHERE lastname = '$lname' AND date_of_birth = '$dob'
```

Comment: it's still not printing the data of the selected array

Comment: echo $firstname;

echo $lastname;

echo $date_of_birth;

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","dbpassword") or die("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Could not connect to the database");

 $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['lastname']); 
    $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['date_of_birth']); 
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qfever WHERE lastname = '$lname' AND date_of_birth = '$dob'");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];
 }
 echo $firstname;
 echo $lastname;

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jeremiah Winsley in a comment:

> First, you're mixing mysqli and mysql. Second, you have the wrong syntax for [_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in either variant.

The ops problem lay in them getting confused between `mysqli_` and `mysql_`.  This was confirmed by their edit to the question saying:

> SOLVED, I mixed mysqli_ and mysql_ **